# Change filetype association on OS X?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, file-association, quicktime, mpg

Quicktime X does not want to play certain MPG files. How do I change the default to be VLC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right-click on the file and select *'Get Info'* (or press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> when the file is selected in the Finder), you can expand the *'Open With'* section, pick an application, and click *'Change All'*. It will pop up a confirmation box to which you will click continue:

[image]

This should change the opening program for all files with that extension. Cheers!