# On a Mac, how do you start TextEdit or TextMate from a shell? (bash)

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, textmate, textedit

I tried and the only way seemed like typing in

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

in a bash shell.  But even when I close the application, it is not considered an exit. I need to go to the app icon on the dock and click "Quit" so that it will exit.

Any other way to invoke and exit it?  thanks.

Comment: Multi-document applications (like *TextEdit*) do not automatically quit even if all of their windows have been closed. So, if you mean “close all the application’s windows” when you say “close the application”, that would explain why you do not see it exit at the shell. Switch to the application and use its Quit menu item (usually, ⌘Q).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `mate [file]` to open it from the shell.

This does require that you [link this](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/textmate-shell-utility-tmmate/), but it's fairly easy and I believe it might already be an option in the preferences. **Just checked, go to "Help" -> "Terminal Usage" in the menubar**.

You can also use `mate .` (note the `.`) to open the entire current folder as a project in TextMate.

Comment: Brilliant stuff~ :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd read the [MacRumours guide for `open`](http://guides.macrumors.com/open), namely running `open -e file.txt` to open the file with TextEdit, and (if you have set TextWrangler as the default for .txt files) `open -t file.txt` to open it with TextWrangler (or whatever you have set the default program to). If you're looking to set the default for a file type, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/150816).

Comment: Besides *TextEdit* and the default text editor, *open* can also launch any application by name : `open -a 'AppleScript Editor'` and `open -a 'QuickTime Player' some_media_pathname`.

Answer (score 2):

open your .bash_profile using for example:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

at the end of the file paste the following:

```
# TextMate
o(){
open $1 -a textmate.app
}
```

reload your profile:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

usage:

```
o myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For TextMate, just type 'mate filename' in shell. Directory name works too.